# Cannot solve simple non-linear differential equation with the control library

Tags: python, ode, differential-equations

I wanted to implement a simple non-linear system to test the control library but I do get an error which I do not understand.

Example:

```py
import control
import numpy as np

def simple_update(t, x, u, params={}):
    dx = 3 * x[0]**2
    return dx


io_simple = control.NonlinearIOSystem(simple_update,
                                      None,
                                      states=('x'),
                                      name='simple')

X0 = 2  # Initial
time_sequence = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)

# Simulate the system
t, y = control.input_output_response(io_simple, time_sequence, 0, X0)
```

But it yields this error:

> lib\site-packages\control\iosys.py", line 1624, in input_output_response
> y[:, i] = sys._out(T[i], soln.y[:, i], u)

> IndexError: index 2 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2

Does anyone understand the problem or can give me a hint how to debug this problem? Does it have something to do with the ode solver?

Comment: I don't have the control package, but I'd try using X0 as an array instead.

Comment: @PeterMeisrimel Still does not work. Actually, the code works if I only erase the square. Therefore, I guess it has something to do with the solver.